# Error with all pagespeed test tools

Tags: seo, page-speed, error, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to reduce my pagespeed loading time

However all tools I try to use give an error. Google pagespeed insights gives a backend error, pindom tool just says it does not work and webpagetest.org only finished 1/3 of the full test.

Does anyone know why I get these errors and how to solve them?

Comment: When asking for help, saying "i have an error" is less useful than saying: "I have attempted to do X, I expected Y, but instead got error Z", with full details, without reinterpreting the messages. So you may wish to expand your question with more factual data, especially since you say "why I get these errors" and none knows specifically which errors you are referencing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I can’t provide anymore details on the errors since the sites don’t give any more information. The only detail I get is “backend error” by google pagespeed insights. I thought maybe some others when experiencing this problem and could help me.

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting one - get the same exception testing your site, however, there is a way around this ;)

Let's start with the bad news - Your Mobile Site Performance only lands a rating of 13 out of 100 (simulating a 4G Network on mobile).

Now the good news - 1st your SEO effort gets a score of 100 by Lighthouse (google insights). Now how did I retrieve the results? There are two ways:

**1. Option:**

- Install Google Chrome [Developer Extension](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).
- Making sure you also add the [LIghthouse Extension](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/)
- Visit your site on chrome and open the Developer Console (Option + CMD + I)
- Go to "Audit" tab
- Setup the test (mobile or desktop, network speed, etc.) and run the audit :)

**2. Option**

Run the tests in batch in a terminal window (this is awesome if you want to test multiple pages at the same time - that's standard practice with our clients. Here are tow articles that tells you how - [Windows](https://edit.co.uk/blog/save-time-by-batch-processing-lighthouse-audit-files-from-the-command-line/) / [Mac](https://www.upbuild.io/blog/lighthouse-reports-multiple-pages/).